# Configurable product still displayed but accosiated simple product is out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, stock, out-of-stock

I have a configurable product with 2 simple accosiated products (size 41,42).
Two simple product is out of stock but when i enter product page of configurable product i see that has two available option 41 and 42. If i select one of this option and then press add to cart button i get a message such "This product is currently out of stock"

I have check catalog /inventory settings (manage stock, backorder and set out of stock if qnt = 0).

Also i have decache and reindex

Now i use magento 1.9. I think that with 1.7 i havent this problem.

Any idea?

Comment: AFAIK, Configurable product doesn't go out of stock even if it's all child products are out of stock. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I had the same issue I now have a cron job set up that updates the products every day see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138352/auto-update-configurable-products-stock-status-with-a-cron-job Hope it helps

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138368/magento-1-update-configurable-stock-based-on-child-products-stocks