# Auto Update Configurable Products Stock Status with a cron job

Tags: php, cron, stock, inventory, out-of-stock

I have the following script which I run to tell me if there are any configurable products the have their stock availability setting set incorrectly.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
$emailcheck = 0;

foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct) {
    /**
    * Load product by product id
    */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());

    /**
    * Process All Products
    */




        /**
        * Get children products (all associated children products data)
        */
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

        $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();

        if($stockItem->getIsInStock()){
            /**
            * All configurable products, which are in stock
            */

            $instock_childrenisinstock = false;

            foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
                $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($childProduct)->getQty();
                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $instock_childrenisinstock = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$instock_childrenisinstock) {
                echo "<p>".$product->getName()." (".$product->getId().") is <span style='font-weight: bold;color: red'>IN STOCK<span></p>";

            }

        } else {
            /**
            * All configurable products, which are out of stock
            */

            $outofstock_childrenisinstock = false;

            foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
                $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($childProduct)->getQty();
                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $outofstock_childrenisinstock = true;
                }
            }
            if ($outofstock_childrenisinstock) {
                echo "<p>".$product->getName()." (".$product->getId().") is <span style='font-weight: bold;color: red'>OUT OF STOCK<span></p>";

            }
        }

}

?>
```

This will list on screen any configurable products that are set incorrectly.
I have another very similar script which runs on cron to send me an email if the script has a result.
So my process is I receive a notification email(from cron job) I run the above script and then change the products manually through the magento backend.

Can I alter this script so that it runs on a cron job and automatically updates the configurable products? It seems like it should be easy but I'm a complete php noob so I'm looking for some help.

My thoughts are the code:

```
echo "<p>".$product->getName()." (".$product->getId().") is <span style='font-weight: bold;color: red'>IN STOCK<span></p>";
```

Should be replaced with something like: product(ID) set to out of stock
But I have no idea what the code is for this.

Cheers

New Code From Nidheesh Implemented:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
$emailcheck = 0;

foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct) {
    /**
    * Load product by product id
    */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());

    /**
    * Process All Products
    */




        /**
        * Get children products (all associated children products data)
        */
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

        $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();

        if($stockItem->getIsInStock()){
            /**
            * All configurable products, which are in stock
            */

            $instock_childrenisinstock = false;

            foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
                $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($childProduct)->getQty();
                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $instock_childrenisinstock = true;
                }
            }

            // Addition From @Nidheesh
            $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
            $stockItem->save();
            //To Make sure reindex is running
            $product->save();

        } else {
            /**
            * All configurable products, which are out of stock
            */

            $outofstock_childrenisinstock = false;


            foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
        $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($childProduct)->getQty();
        if ($qty > 0) {
            $instock_childrenisinstock = true;

            break; // Addition From @Nidheesh
        }
    }
            // Addition From @Nidheesh
            $stockItem->setIsInStock(false);
            $stockItem->save();
            //To Make sure reindex is running
            $product->save();
        }

}

?>
```

Comment: Tried the above script as suggested by Nidheesh but I get no result. Doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete script will looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
$emailcheck = 0;

foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct) {
    /**
     * Load product by product id
     */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());

    /**
     * Process All Products
     */
    /**
     * Get children products (all associated children products data)
     */
    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $product);

    $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();

    if (!$stockItem->getIsInStock()) {
        /**
         * All configurable products, which are in stock
         */
        $instock_childrenisinstock = false;

        foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($childProduct)->getQty();
            if ($qty > 0) {
                $instock_childrenisinstock = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($instock_childrenisinstock) {
            $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
            $stockItem->save();
            //To Make sure reindex is running
            $product->save();
        }
    } else {
        /**
         * All configurable products, which are out of stock
         */
        $outofstock_childrenisinstock = false;


        foreach ($childProducts as $childProduct) {
            $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($childProduct)->getQty();
            if ($qty > 0) {
                $instock_childrenisinstock = true;

                break; 
            }
        }
        if (!$instock_childrenisinstock) {
            $stockItem->setIsInStock(false);
            $stockItem->save();
            //To Make sure reindex is running
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @ZUBU Check and let me know if any problem

Comment: I'll give both of these a try. Is the alternative method a php script? The code looks very similar

Comment: Yes, it's also a php script but using direct sql queries to get the instock/out of stock config products to speed up the process than using collection

Comment: Hi @Nidheesh I have tried the above code and it seems to run without any errors but it is not changing the status of any products. No Errors it just runs for about 2-3 mins(Using Putty). Any Ideas?? Also tried running the other script (can't comment there as I dont have enough rep but I'm getting a syntax error. Don't know if I should post about that question here??

Comment: Better you paste the syntax error here

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in /home/zubu/public_html/devsite/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Comment: I got the above script working. The setinstock values were the wrong way around. I will post my new working script soon.

Comment: The variable name **$outofstockConfigurableQuery** was the problem in first query

Comment: @ZUBU I have updated the answer, please accept it as answer if that help you

Comment: I have my if statements around the other way which had me confused for a while but this script is now working. Thank you